# How does SciPy's Welch function change the shape of the data?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I am working with some time series data with a shape of 8064. The data is actually the popular EEG data called DEAP. It basically is a 3D array of size (40, 40, 8064) and here is the [link](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/mmv/datasets/deap/) to the official dataset website.

I applied Welch in order to get the PSD (Power Spectral Density) of the data but the PSD result has a different shape. I was trying to figure out how Welch changes the shape of the data. Any ideas?

```
srate = 128
winsize = int( 2*srate ) # 2-second window
hannw = .5 - np.cos(2*np.pi*np.linspace(0,1,winsize))/2
nfft = srate*100 # number of FFT points (frequency resolution)
f, welchpow = scipy.signal.welch(data1, fs=srate, window=hannw,
                                 nperseg=winsize, noverlap=winsize/2, nfft=nfft)
```

As you can see in the code above, *data1* is the original data and has a shape of (40, 40, 8064). After Applying the code above, *welchpow* will have a shape of (40, 40, 6041). I can't figure out how it actually changes the shape of the time series data from 8064 to 6041.

Comment: Hello & welcome. This question is quite specific to the Welch function, and presumably the implementation of that algorithm, so I don't know if you'll get a good response. Personally I would try running `scipy.signal.welch(data1)` i.e. allow defaults for all other parameters, and see what I get.

Comment: I suggest asking your question on [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst thanks for your comment. I actually did try running the function with the defaults and stuff but couldn't still figure out how the shape changes

Comment: @martineau Thanks I just asked my question there too and here is 
 the link if : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/how-does-scipys-welch-function-change-the-shape-of-the-data